# ASK CLI fails to load AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I'm trying to use the Ask CLI to deploy an Alexa skill, but whenever I run `ask deploy`, I get this error:

```
[Error]: Cannot find the environment variable: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
```

I'm 100% sure the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` env variable is set to a valid access key. This is how I'm setting it in my `~/.zshrc` file:

```sh
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIBJRSRMxxxxxxxxx
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=fS0A6MS9Q9V1OIxKQjKwwaO2fxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

It is also set in my default AWS credentials at `~/.aws/credentials`:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIBJRSRMxxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key=fS0A6MS9Q9V1OIxKQjKwwaO2fxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I've re-run `ask init` multiple times and selected "load from env variables" and logged in through the browser successfully.

I've double checked my `.zshrc` is loaded with `source ~/.zshrc`. I've also echoed `$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` successfully:

```
echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AKIBJRSRMxxxxxxxxx
```

And I've tried running `ask deploy` with the access key variable directly:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIBJRSRMxxxxxxxxx ask deploy
[Error]: Cannot find the environment variable: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
```

And I know these credentials are valid because I created them an hour ago.

The `ask init` prompt even says `We have detected you have AWS environment variables. Would you like to setup your profile using those?` which I answer yes to:

[image: ask cli init and failed deploy]

I've created an issues in the alexa skills kit sdk repo:

https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/issues/531

But the maintainers point other issue authors to SO and the amazon dev forum.

Versions:

- Ask CLI 1.6.4
- Node 10.11.0
- NPM 6.4.1
- Mac OSX Mojave 10.14.2
- AWS CLI `aws-cli/1.16.56 Python/2.7.13 Darwin/18.2.0 botocore/1.12.46`

**EDIT:**

I was able to deploy successfully by downgrading to `ask-cli@1.6.1`. It appears this bug was introduced in `ask-cli@1.6.2`.

Comment: please add the output of `ask --version` to the question (1.6.4 according to the bug report)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in that version of the CLI.  Current workaround is to use AWS credentials in your `~/.aws` profile and not environment variables.

I forwarded this question to the appropriate team @ Alexa.

Comment: I have the same credentials set `~/.aws/credentials` as `[default]`.